# Download Manager, app store

Tags: download-manager

First of all forgive me, as I have very little knowledge about computers.
I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't Ubuntu have a download manager installed by default?
2. Why are so many commonly used applications like Opera browser, or variety wallpaper changers, or many other stuff not present in the Ubuntu app store, athough they are supported by Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer 1**: Because packaged browsers (Chrome and Firefox) have embedded download managers, but they are not very feature rich so you can try this **uGet** download manager it is nice, lightweight and well-supported in Ubuntu. [uGet Download Manager](http://ugetdm.com/)

**Answer 2**: Not every application would be on Ubuntu app store because applications may not be officially approved by Ubuntu app store or developers want to download our app from their official site or any other reason can be. If you want to download any app you first go to official app store if you would not find anything interesting then of course you would find at Google Search.

Comment: Add to Answer #1: uGet is definitely the best choice for that. :)

Comment: Add to Answer #2: Ubuntu doesn't support all the apps in the Ubuntu software center...the long answer is that some apps are made specifically for Ubuntu and do not support Debian...in those case the app is usually not in the official app store because they first have to be pulled from Debian. Apps made just to support Ubuntu use PPAs which are fine to use if the PPA is from a credible source. For example, the PPA listed on [uGet's site](http://ugetdm.com/downloads-ubuntu) is perfectly safe to use...though that can't be guaranteed for all PPAs.

Answer (score 0):

Opera can be obtained by going to the website. The App store in Ubuntu is developer submitted and depending on the license the software is developed under, it doesn't always get in there.